# Unity 2D: Making the Player Gameobject Reactivate after being turned off

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I can't get the Player Gameobject to reappear. The player deactivates the moment the Timeline starts when they touch the box collider, but the player never reactivates. I have tried using Player.SetActive(true) in the coroutine and even using an Invoke method with no luck. Any ideas on how to fix this? Please help.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Playables;

public class TimelineTrigger : MonoBehaviour
{
    // calling items for Unity
    public PlayableDirector timeline;
    public GameObject Player;
    public GameObject CutsceneCollider;
    public GameObject CutsceneMC;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        // calls the playable director and turns off the MC for the scene
        timeline = timeline.GetComponent<PlayableDirector>();
        CutsceneMC.SetActive(false);
    }

    void Update()
    {
        Player = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player");
    }

    private void EnableAfterTimeline()
    {
        Player = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player");
        Player.SetActive(true);
    }

    public void OnTriggerEnter2D (Collider2D col)
    {
        if (col.CompareTag("Player"))
        {
            // plays the cutscene and starts the timer
            timeline.Play();
            Player.SetActive(false);
            Invoke("EnableAfterTimeline", 18);
            CutsceneMC.SetActive(true);
            StartCoroutine(FinishCut());
        }

        IEnumerator FinishCut()
        {
            // once the cutscene is over using the duration, turns off the collider and the MC.
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(17);
            CutsceneMC.SetActive(false);
            CutsceneCollider.SetActive(false);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Objects can be re-instantiated using the Instantiate method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is that [coroutines](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html) in Unity can't be run on inactive GameObjects, so FinishCut never gets executed.

This can be worked around by having a separate MonoBehaviour in the scene to which the responsibility of running a coroutine can be off-loaded. This even makes it possible to start static coroutines from static methods.

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;

[AddComponentMenu("")] // Hide in the Add Component menu to avoid cluttering it
public class CoroutineHandler : MonoBehaviour
{
    private static MonoBehaviour monoBehaviour;
    
    private static MonoBehaviour MonoBehaviour
    {
        get
        {
            var gameObject = new GameObject("CoroutineHandler");
            gameObject.hideFlags = HideFlags.HideAndDontSave; // hide in the hierarchy
            DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject); // have the object persist from one scene to the next
            monoBehaviour = gameObject.AddComponent<CoroutineHandler>();
            return monoBehaviour;
        }
    }
    
    public static new Coroutine StartCoroutine(IEnumerator coroutine)
    {
        return MonoBehaviour.StartCoroutine(coroutine);
    }
}
```

Then you just need to tweak your code a little bit to use this CoroutineHandler to run the coroutine instead of your inactive GameObject.

```
public void OnTriggerEnter2D (Collider2D col)
{
    if (col.CompareTag("Player"))
    {
        // plays the cutscene and starts the timer
        timeline.Play();
        Player.SetActive(false);
        Invoke("EnableAfterTimeline", 18);
        CutsceneMC.SetActive(true);
        CoroutineHandler.StartCoroutine(FinishCut()); // <- Changed
    }

    IEnumerator FinishCut()
    {
        // once the cutscene is over using the duration, turns off the collider and the MC.
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(17);
        CutsceneMC.SetActive(false);
        CutsceneCollider.SetActive(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: Where would I put the Coroutine Handler script? Because I attached it to a new empty gameobject, and for a spit second the player turned back on, but the timeline repeated. Where before the Coroutine Handler was in the scene, the timeline finished. Unity also returns this error:UnityException: Internal_CreateGameObject is not allowed to be called from a MonoBehaviour constructor (or instance field initializer), call it in Awake or Start instead. Called from MonoBehaviour 'CoroutineHandler' on game object 'Player'.

Comment: Okay it looks like creating the instance inside a static constructor isn't allowed. I modified the code a little bit to use a property instead.

You don't need to put the CoroutineHandler anywhere, it should get automatically created for you behind the scenes when you call CoroutineHandler.StartCoroutine.

Comment: I just removed the coroutine handler script, and the entire thing works! Thank you so much! It's had me stuck for days.

Answer (score 0):

If you have only one Player instance and it's accessible from the start, you'd better set it once in the Start method.

```
void Start()
{
    // calls the playable director and turns off the MC for the scene
    timeline = timeline.GetComponent<PlayableDirector>();
    CutsceneMC.SetActive(false);
    Player = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player");
}

void Update()
{
}

private void EnableAfterTimeline()
{
    Player.SetActive(true);
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I didn't really think that mattered tbh. It made no difference to the issue of the Player gameobject not reappearing. But I did make that change to the script.

Comment: `FindGameObjectWithTag` only returns active object. When you called it in `EnableAfterTimeline`, you set the value to null, that's the difference.